# Disable/Enable Send button in mailComposeController

Tags: ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, mfmailcomposer

How to disable/enable the send button in mailComposeController. I want disable/enable the send button by using through programmatically.Is it passable?  [image]

Can any one help me.

Thank you...

Answer (score 1):

You don't have access to Send and Cancel button of **MFMailComposeViewController**. These buttons and their action are pre-defined and are not meant to be changed.

From Apple Docs:

> Important: The mail composition interface itself is not customizable and must not be modified by your application. 
>   In addition, after presenting the interface, your application is not allowed to make further changes to the email content.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is even possible or not but you can customize navigation bar in case you want to toggle `Send` mail button. Following article can be useful.

http://davidjhinson.wordpress.com/2010/11/24/changing-the-navigation-bar-with-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller/

Answer (score 0):

One way is that you prevent the user to insert text in To: field but it wouldn't be the proper solution

Answer (score 0):

It's default functionality that if the `To` address field is blank then send button is DISABLE..